# Which Newton's Identities are being referred to here?

Tags: power-series, symmetric-polynomials

I do not understand this line of [Wikipedia's page on the Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler_attacks_the_problem):

> If we formally multiply out this product and collect all the $x^2$ terms (we are allowed to do so because of [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)), we see that the $x^2$ coefficient of $\sin(x)/x$ is...

Which Newton identity? How?

Comment: It would be kind to provide links to [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler_attacks_the_problem) and [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)

Comment: "Newton's identities" look like a red herring in this argument. (Sometimes people try to compress an idea in a mathematical argument with a named result, but such hints can be more puzzling than the direct proof.) I would change the wiki article to read: "if we formally multiply out this product and collect all the $x^2$ terms, we see that the $x^2$ coefficient of ..." Play a few finite products to convince yourself.

Comment: @Jerry: a few more details, and I think that could be an answer... :)

Comment: Still not understanding. I done some products, but have nothing to do with the final series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jerry says, it appears someone was trying to be pedantic.

What is meant is that for a polynomial $f(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$ with roots $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$, we have:

$$a_{n-1} = -\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n}\alpha_i$$
$$a_{n-2} = \sum_{1 \leq i_i < i_2 \leq n} \alpha_{i_1}\alpha_{i_2}$$
$$\dots$$
$$a_0 = (-1)^n\alpha_1 \dots \alpha_n.$$

You can see this by expanding $(z-\alpha_1)\dots (z-\alpha_n)$ and comparing with the coefficients of $f(z)$.

To solve the Basel problem, Euler did the same thing with the product expansion of $\frac{\sin z}{z}$, as if it were an infinite degree polynomial, and comparing with the Taylor expansion of $\frac{\sin z}{z}$.

Comment: To be clear, it is a terribly flawed idea that one can treat entire functions like polynomials by expecting them to be determined by their zeros, up to a multiplicative constant. The obvious counterexample is exp(x) which is nonconstant but has no zeros.

More generally, the Weierstrass Product Theorem says that an entire function is determined by its zeros up to a factor of the form exp(h(x)) for a general entire function h(x).